# How to validate JPQL (JPA query) programmatically

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I am looking for a way to validate JPA query programmatically.

Within a (Spring) transaction, I have a list of queries to run. These queries can contain syntax errors which I would like to catch so that the transaction can continue.

My first idea was to use the `EntityManager` and create and execute my queries, and in case they fail, then I could simply catch the exception, log a warning and continue.

The problem is that when a problem occurs, the transaction is flagged for rollbackOnly so my current transaction is rolled back which is not what I want.

In pseudo code, it goes more or less like this:

```
  EntityManager em = ...;
  em.getTransaction().begin();
  List<String> queries = Arrays.asList("select e from Department d", 
             "select d from Department d");
  for(String query:queries) {
       TypedQuery<Department> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query, Department.class); // This can throw an exception
       List<Department> deps = typedQuery.getResultList(); // This can also throw an exception
       //... do some stuff with the departements
  }
```

The alternative I found so far was to create another `EntityManager` from the original one (`em.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager()`), run first my queries in that one and then re-execute them (in case of success) in the original one, but this is really not efficient and looks quite ugly.

I am using EclipseLink as a JPA implementation and I cannot switch to another JPA implementation.

Comment: EclipseLink should have a `jpql.validation` extension, which can validate JPQL expression with HermesParser.

Comment: If you can use annotations, then maybe something like @Transactional(noRollbackFor=BadSqlGrammarException.class)

Comment: @6ton unfortunately, this something internal to eclipselink (and maybe JPA), so modifying the annotation won't  chanfe anything.

Comment: @meskobalazs do you have additional info on that parser and how it is to be used?

Comment: Try take a look at **Nested Unit of Work** https://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_Transactions_(ELUG)#Nested_Unit_of_Work 
 The main point from documentation is **Failure of a nested unit of work does not affect the commit or rollback transaction of other operations in the parent unit of work.** Hope this is one you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want complile-time validation for JPQL. There is no way to check if the query syntax is correct.

In order to do the job you want, use the criteria api instead of JPQL. 
Check the documentation for the criteria api. You will need to user metamodel for compile-time checking

Comment: How could I use the CriteriaBuilder with a String fetched from a database?

Comment: Please chech the official documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjrij.html

Comment: Criteria api uses object-level operations.

Comment: I know that, but it cannot be used in this situation as the queries are written by users in the DB.

Comment: If I understand correct, the queries you want to run are written from other users in the db and then you retrieve them.